# How can I recognize 1-1,1-M and M-N relationship in SQL Server by query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, orm, relationship

I have a query like this

```
SELECT 
    RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME FKName, 
    KF.TABLE_SCHEMA FKSchema,
    KF.TABLE_NAME FKTable, 
    KF.COLUMN_NAME FKColumn,
    RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME PKName,
    KP.TABLE_SCHEMA PKSchema,
    KP.TABLE_NAME PKTable, 
    KP.COLUMN_NAME PKColumn, 
    RC.MATCH_OPTION MatchOption, 
    RC.UPDATE_RULE UpdateRule,
    RC.DELETE_RULE DeleteRule
FROM
    [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS] RC
JOIN 
    [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[KEY_COLUMN_USAGE] KF ON RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KF.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN 
    [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[KEY_COLUMN_USAGE] KP ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = KP.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

and it have a result like :

```
FK_Person_Address   dbo Person  Id  PK_Address  dbo Address Id  SIMPLE  NO ACTION   NO ACTION --[1-1] or [1-M] or [M-N] I need this!
```

I want to recognize what is the type of relationship in each row 1-1 or 1-M as column with relationship status.

**[1-1] or [1-M] or [M-N] I need this!**

Can any one guide me ?

**EDIT :**

Why I asked this question ? so I see some visual studio extensions like [Reverse poco Generator](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) and [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) can reverse table to C# pocos so they must know relationships status 1-1 or 1-M or M-N for generating Navigation property as single class or list of classes and also create EntityTypeConfiguration for mapping so How they get these info from SQL server tables ? If we dont know any about relationships of tables so we can not reverse them to C# class !

Comment: You *cannot* determine the cardinality of relationships from a single query - you need to look at the **table structure** and how the tables are linked, and how the columns involved are defined.

Comment: Yes, these tools know the cardinality of the relationships **by looking at the table structure!**

Comment: Do you have any sample I can not recognize your description ? How can I looking at the tables structure? with which technique or query ?

Comment: There are systems tables with that infomation.

Answer (score -1):

For 1-1 relationship : There is unique keyword with foreign key constraints in referenced table.

For M-1 relationship : There is no unique keyword with foreign key constraints in referenced table.

Comment: Your answer is not SQL; it doesn't have to be in all caps. Please obey the standard rules of English spelling, grammar, punctuation, and capitalization.